# Botões desabilitados na área de análise

Tags: suporte, filas-de-análise

Algumas vezes quando vou fazer uma análise, não aparece todos os botões. Neste caso o botão "terminei" está desabilitado, isto é decorrente do quê? Era para haver mais botões, vito que em outras análises existem botões de "editar" e "fechar"? Ou algum membro já havia concluído esta análise?

[image: imagem]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você clicar em "(mais)", logo após o trecho explicativo na caixa dos botões, aparecerá o seguinte texto que responde parte da sua pergunta:

> **Nenhuma ação necessária** quando esta publicação não precisa de nenhuma
> ação de sua parte.
>
> **Terminei** só está disponível se você tiver feito o seguinte:
>
> - **Votar a favor ou contra** para classificar a qualidade e a utilidade da
>   pergunta
> - **Editar** para melhorar a aparência ou clareza da pergunta
> - **Comentar** para deixar um feedback construtivo ao autor ou votar a favor
>   dos comentários existentes
> - **Sinalizar** para notificar os moderadores de
>   problemas graves
> - **Encerrar** perguntas que não podem ou não devem ser
>   respondidas aqui
>
> Não esqueça de **deixar um comentário** se puder ajudar o
> usuário, **votar a favor da pergunta** se não puder encontrar nenhum
> problema com ela ou clique em **Ignorar** se não tem certeza e deseja ir
> para o próximo item.

Ou seja, para clicar em "Terminei" você deve ter tomado alguma ação, senão significa que você nem começou :) que seria então o caso de escolher "Nenhuma ação necessária".

Além disso, cada fila de análise possui uma quantidade de botões pré-definidos. Pode ser meio confuso no começo, mas se você observar, sempre serão os mesmo três botões para a fila de "Primeiras Publicações". Para as outras filas podem ou não ser outras quantidades de botões com outros ou os mesmos textos, variando de acordo com a necessidade da análise da fila.

O único caso (que eu me lembro) de fila de análise que muda a quantidade de botões é para a fila de análise de edição de wiki de tags, que ao alcançar o privilégio de Usuário Confiável (20K de rep) aparece o botão de "Melhorar". Mas no geral, o que acontece é que a UI não fica escondendo os botões de acordo com a ação que você tomou na análise, o que ela faz é desabilitar, mas ainda deixando-o visível.